# Calculation result differs between Excel and Python

Tags: python-2.7, excel-formula

I'm very new to Python so am likely missing some nuance but I can't understand why the following calculations result in different values:

```
n: 0.00167322032899
```

Excel

```
(15 / 8) * n ^ 2
5.24937425502263E-06
```

Python

```
(15/8) * n ** 2
2.79966626935e-06
```

I've made some attempts at replicating Python's result in Excel with bracket usage but to no avail. Any guidance?

Comment: Python 2 returns an integer for integer division, not a float/double. So you need to do `(15.0 / 8) * n ^ 2` so it knows to return a floating point value.

Comment: @zerk Only Python2 behave this way, not anymore with Python3.

Comment: The integer division is not the only thing you have to be careful about. Take in account that `0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 == 0.3` returns `False`, and that `056 == 56` also evaluates `False`. The reasons are different than your question but is something you also have to be careful about when programming :)

Comment: Excellent, thank you everyone for the quick advice. I'll accept Ignacio's answer as it was the first and most concise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Division in Python 2.x is integer division by default.

```
>>> (15. / 8) * 0.00167322032899 ** 2
5.2493742550226314e-06
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> (15 / 8) * 0.00167322032899 ** 2
5.2493742550226314e-06
```

Answer (score 4):

In python, 15/8 is equal to 1 whereas in Excel, it would be equal to 1.875. Python 2 considers 15 and 8 as integer and therefore perfoms an integer division. You can try:

`(15.0/8) * n ** 2` or `(15/8.0) * n ** 2` which would give you `5.249374255022632e-06`.

Answer (score 3):

Doing `15 / 8` in Python (python2) does integer division. So you get `1`, whereas Excel evaluates that to `1.875`

I assume you want a fraction, so in python use `15.0 / 8` (or `15 / 8.0` or `15.0 / 8.0`) to force a fraction instead of integer division